# PHP fails when date and format have different separators

Tags: php

So here's what happens:

```
var_dump(date_create_from_format('d.m.Y', '29-04-2018'));
```

or this:

```
var_dump(date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', '29.04.2018'));
```

and

```
var_dump(date_get_last_errors());
```

outputs:

```
    array (size=4)
      'warning_count' => int 0
      'warnings' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'error_count' => int 4
      'errors' => 
        array (size=2)
          2 => string 'Unexpected data found.' (length=22)
          5 => string 'Unexpected data found.' (length=22)
```

But when format string and date string have same separator (dash or dot) it works.
What am I doing wrong?

UPD: This code is from Chauffeur Booking System Plugin for Wordpress. And it is intended to set all dates to standard format in order to compare them later.
So it takes the standard format from settings of plugin and the date that was chosen or typed somewhere in the frontend. And it converts this date to this standard format to compare it to other dates set in plugin. I hope this makes sense.

Tested on php 5.6 and 7.0.

Comment: You're telling PHP to use one format and passing another? I think that should be obvious why that doesn't work.

Comment: I guess my problem is that **you don't have to pass a format here**. `new DateTime()` will accept both strings. If you specify a format, as you're doing here, and it's not in that format, you can and should expect failure. So I'm not sure what your question is

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Convert dash to dot and vice versa?

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen I've updated the question to answer yours. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Machavity said, you're misusing `date_create_from_format` function, you must pass same format.

If you want to change the format to something else, try this:

```
var_dump(date('d.m.Y', time('29-04-2018')));
var_dump(date('d-m-Y', time('29.04.2018')));
```

Note: This will return string of the desired format, on the other hand, `date_create_from_format` returns `DateTime` object. I believe that's what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I finally understand that this function was not intended to change datetime format but simply to create DateTime object of it.